# Optimizing gradient function in C++

Tags: c++, performance, opencv

I'm computing the gradient of an image manually (without using built in functions) and I want to make it faster but keeping the same performance.
I'm very open to any suggestions.. currently learning c++ optimzation and STL lib in recent c++.

Here is my code, my main concern is `gradiantAndDirection` function that I need to optimize. The `TimerAvrg struct` is how I compute the running time of that function:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>


struct   TimerAvrg
{
    std::vector<double> times;
    size_t curr=0,n;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin,end;
    TimerAvrg(int _n=30)
    {
        n=_n;
        times.reserve(n);
    }

    inline void start()
    {
        begin= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }

    inline void stop()
    {
        end= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        double duration=double(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-begin).count())*1e-6;
        if ( times.size()<n)
            times.push_back(duration);
        else{
            times[curr]=duration;
            curr++;
            if (curr>=times.size()) curr=0;}
    }

    double getAvrg()
    {
        double sum=0;
        for(auto t:times)
            sum+=t;
        return sum/double(times.size());
    }
};

//Those variables will be in a class with gradiantAndDirection
uchar *dirImg;
int gradThresh = 20;

void gradiantAndDirection(cv::Mat& GxGy, const cv::Mat &grey)
{
    cv::Mat smoothImage;
    GaussianBlur(grey, smoothImage, cv::Size(5, 5), 1.0);
    uchar *smoothImg = smoothImage.data;

    GxGy.create( grey.size(),CV_16SC1);
    short* gradImg = (short*)GxGy.data;

    dirImg = new unsigned char[grey.cols*grey.rows];

    //Initialization of row = 0, row = height-1, column=0, column=width-1 
    for (int j = 0; j<grey.cols; j++)
        gradImg[j] = gradImg[(grey.rows - 1)*grey.cols + j] = gradThresh - 1;

    for (int i = 1; i<grey.rows - 1; i++)
        gradImg[i*grey.cols] = gradImg[(i + 1)*grey.cols - 1] = gradThresh - 1;

    for (int i = 1; i<grey.rows - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j<grey.cols - 1; j++) {
            int com1 = smoothImg[(i + 1)*grey.cols + j + 1] - smoothImg[(i - 1)*grey.cols + j - 1];
            int com2 = smoothImg[(i - 1)*grey.cols + j + 1] - smoothImg[(i + 1)*grey.cols + j - 1];
            int gx;
            int gy;
            gx = abs(com1 + com2 +  (smoothImg[i*grey.cols + j + 1] - smoothImg[i*grey.cols + j - 1]));
            gy = abs(com1 - com2 +  (smoothImg[(i + 1)*grey.cols + j] - smoothImg[(i - 1)*grey.cols + j]));
            int sum;
            if(0)
                sum = gx + gy;
            else
                sum = (int)sqrt((double)gx*gx + gy*gy);

            int index = i*grey.cols + j;
            gradImg[index] = sum;
            if (sum >= gradThresh) {
                if (gx >= gy) dirImg[index] = 1;//1 vertical
                else      dirImg[index] = 2;//2 Horizontal
            }
        }
    }
}


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    cv::Mat image;
    image = cv::imread(argv[1], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);   

    float sum=0;
    cv::Mat GxGy;
    for(int alpha = 0; alpha <20 ; alpha++)
    {
        TimerAvrg Fps;
        Fps.start();
        gradiantAndDirection(GxGy, image);
        Fps.stop();
        sum = sum + Fps.getAvrg()*1000;
    }

    std::cout << "\rTime detection=" << sum/19 << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
    cv::resize(GxGy,GxGy,cv::Size(image.cols/2,image.rows/2));
    cv::Mat result8UC1;
    cv::convertScaleAbs(GxGy, result8UC1);
    cv::imshow( "Display window",result8UC1);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile my code under Ubuntu 16.04 gcc 8.1.0

```
g++ -std=c++1z -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -ffast-math -mmmx -msse -msse2 -msse3 -DNDEBUG -Wall improve_code.cpp -o improve_code -fopenmp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make it faster but keeping the same performance" - isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: @TobySpeight I think we can make a faster program but sometimes we loose the optimal performance like calling "a.empty()" instead of "a.size() == 0" ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Include what you use

We use `std::abs` and `std::vector` but the code lacks the necessary includes:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
```

## Perform a single task well

Why do we perform the Gaussian blur?  What if the input is already sufficiently blurred, or if it needs a bigger kernel?

If we make the caller responsible for this preparation step, we give it more control, and we can focus on a single responsibility in this function.

## Fix the memory leak

This allocation is never released:

```
dirImg = new unsigned char[grey.cols*grey.rows];
```

In fact, this entire (global) array seems only to be assigned to, and never used, so we could remove it entirely.

## Simplified indexing

It might be easier to use `index` throughout, and add rows or columns directly with ±`grey.cols` and ±`1`:

```
      const int index = i*grey.cols + j;
      int com1 = smoothImg[index + grey.cols + 1] - smoothImg[index - grey.cols - 1];
      int com2 = smoothImg[index - grey.cols + 1] - smoothImg[index + grey.cols - 1];
      int gx = std::abs(com1 + com2
                        + smoothImg[index + 1] - smoothImg[index + 1]);
      int gy = std::abs(com1 - com2
                        + smoothImg[index + grey.cols] - smoothImg[index - grey.cols]);
```

## Use the standard library

There's no need to (badly) re-write `std::hypot()` for the computation of `sum` (also, drop the `if (0)` - that's always false).

```
      const int sum = std::hypot(gx, gy);
```

## Saturate, don't overflow

The `std::hypot()` value could conceivably be larger than the range of `int`, or of `gradImg[]` (depending on the relative sizes of the target's integer types) - in such cases, we should `std::clamp` the value to the possible range, rather than suffering Undefined Behaviour.

## Spelling

Prefer standard spelling: **gradient**, not <s>gradiant</s>.